# Duplicate entry '1' for ForeignKey in Testing Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, integration-testing

I'm implementing an integration test in Selenium for Django

I have a Model *example* like this:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(max_length=11, primary_key=True)
    contract_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    productType= models.OneToOneField(
        ProductType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='product_type_id'
    )
    productGroup = models.ForeignKey(
        productGroup,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="ProductGroup",
        db_column='product_group_id'
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'PRODUCT'
```

When I insert a new field to my product
I got an error like this. The problem is, when I insert or create a new product for the first time, it is still working well. But the second time, it raises an error

```py
"Duplicate entry '3' for key 'product_type_id'"
```

I think because table `PRODUCT_TYPE` have a constraint `product_type_id`, but the value I insert has duplicate. But can I fix foreignKey constrain errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `OneToOneField`, the first time you add a product with ProductType (let's say X) it will work fine. If you add new `Product` with the `ProductType` X, it will encounter duplicate (`OneToOneField` allows one product to be mapped to only 1 `ProductType`)

Comment: So, how can I fix it, 
change to `ForeignKey` ?